# How to align the text as the same row of the picture?

Tags: html, css

Learning CSS, this is the sample code.
The text block "TITLE HEADING" is behind the picture, how to move it to the same row as the picture ?

```css
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">

<body class="w3-light-grey">
  <!-- w3-content defines a container for fixed size centered content, 
    and is wrapped around the whole page content, except for the footer in this example -->
  <div class="w3-content" style="max-width:1400px">
    <!-- Header -->
    <header class="w3-container w3-center w3-padding-32">
      <h1><b>MY BLOG</b></h1>
      <p>Welcome to the blog of <span class="w3-tag">unknown</span></p>
    </header>
    <div class="w3-row l8 s12">
      <!-- Blog entry -->
      <div class="w3-card-4 w3-margin w3-white">
        <img src="/w3images/woods.jpg" alt="Nature" style="width:100%">
        <div class="w3-container">
          <h3><b>TITLE HEADING</b></h3>
          <h5>Title description, <span class="w3-opacity">April 7, 2014</span></h5>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-container">
          <p>Mauris neque quam, fermentum ut nisl vitae, convallis maximus nisl. Sed mattis nunc id lorem euismod placerat. Vivamus porttitor magna enim, ac accumsan tortor cursus at. Phasellus sed ultricies mi non congue ullam corper. Praesent tincidunt
            sed tellus ut rutrum. Sed vitae justo condimentum, porta lectus vitae, ultricies congue gravida diam non fringilla.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <br>
    <!-- END w3-content -->
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nest those two elements in a parent `.wrapper` and use `flex`.

```css
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  max-width: 50%;
}

.w3-container {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">

<body class="w3-light-grey">
  <!-- w3-content defines a container for fixed size centered content, 
    and is wrapped around the whole page content, except for the footer in this example -->
  <div class="w3-content" style="max-width:1400px">
    <!-- Header -->
    <header class="w3-container w3-center w3-padding-32">
      <h1><b>MY BLOG</b></h1>
      <p>Welcome to the blog of <span class="w3-tag">unknown</span></p>
    </header>
    <div class="w3-row l8 s12">
      <!-- Blog entry -->
      <div class="w3-card-4 w3-margin w3-white">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="Nature" style="width:100%">
          <div class="w3-container">
            <h3><b>TITLE HEADING</b></h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-container">
          <h5>Title description, <span class="w3-opacity">April 7, 2014</span></h5>
          <p>Mauris neque quam, fermentum ut nisl vitae, convallis maximus nisl. Sed mattis nunc id lorem euismod placerat. Vivamus porttitor magna enim, ac accumsan tortor cursus at. Phasellus sed ultricies mi non congue ullam corper. Praesent tincidunt
            sed tellus ut rutrum. Sed vitae justo condimentum, porta lectus vitae, ultricies congue gravida diam non fringilla.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <br>
    <!-- END w3-content -->
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .body {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
    height: 150px;
}

.container {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
}

.imgdiv {
    background-color: green;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

img {
    height: 50px;

}

.textdiv {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}

p {
    padding: auto;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="imgdiv">
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRhWSuoV5RUZiv4vizlSTEFOJCuA6Db5nwvtA&usqp=CAU"
                alt="alternatetext" />
        </div>

        <div class="textdiv">
            <p>some text</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p>some content here</p>
</div>

  
</div>
```

Comment: display: flex;  is away to do it

Comment: Please explain your answer. Don't just dump code and expect everyone to understand what it was that you did.

Comment: it is very easy to understand just use display: flex; for the parent. and this is not a code by any means  I recommend you to read this https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp